# Stack overflow in recursive method

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm writing a program that allows a user to input a set of integers into an array and characteristics of those numbers will be displayed once a zero is entered. I am having an issue with one method:findMaxOfLessThanFirst. Which, of course, finds the maximum number in the array that is also less than the first number entered. Here is the full code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Assignment9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int index = 0;
        int[] numbers;
        numbers = new int[100];

        InputStreamReader inRead = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(inRead);
        String line = buffRead.readLine();

        try {
            while (!line.equals("0") && index < 100) {
                numbers[index] = Integer.parseInt(line);
                index++;
                line = buffRead.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("Array index out of bound");
        }
        int min = findMin(numbers, 0);
        int sumAtEven = computeSumAtEvenIndexes(numbers, 0, numbers.length - 1);
        int divByThree = countDivisibleBy3(numbers, 0, numbers.length - 1);
        int maxLessThanFirst = findMaxOfLessThanFirst(numbers, 1, numbers.length - 1, numbers[0]);
        System.out.println("The minimum number is " + min);
        System.out.println("The sum of numbers at even indexes is " + sumAtEven);
        System.out.println("The count of numbers that are divisible by 3 is " + divByThree);
        System.out.println(
                "The maximum number among numbers that are less than the first number is " + maxLessThanFirst);
    }

    public static int findMin(int[] numbers, int index) {
        if (index == numbers.length - 1) {
            return numbers[index];
        } else {
            return Math.min(numbers[index], findMin(numbers, index + 1));
        }
    }

    public static int computeSumAtEvenIndexes(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        if (startIndex == endIndex) {
            if (startIndex % 2 == 0) {
                return numbers[startIndex];
            } else
                return 0;
        } else {
            if (endIndex % 2 == 0) {
                return computeSumAtEvenIndexes(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1) + numbers[endIndex];
            } else {
                return computeSumAtEvenIndexes(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int countDivisibleBy3(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        if (startIndex == endIndex) {
            if (numbers[startIndex] % 3 == 0) {
                return +2;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else {
            if (numbers[endIndex] == 0) {
                return countDivisibleBy3(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1);
            }
            if (numbers[endIndex] % 3 == 0) {
                return countDivisibleBy3(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1) + 1;
            } else {
                return countDivisibleBy3(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private static int findMaxOfLessThanFirst(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex, int firstNumber) {
        if (startIndex == endIndex) {
            if (numbers[endIndex] <= firstNumber)
                return numbers[startIndex];
        }
        int max = findMaxOfLessThanFirst(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1, firstNumber);
        if (max >= numbers[endIndex] && max <= firstNumber) {
            return max;
        }
        return numbers[endIndex];
    }
}
```

I am sure I'm missing something really elementary here. I just started learning the concept of recursion. So, please be gentle.

Comment: This question has been asked before, although it doesn't have a complete answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148782/how-to-find-a-maximum-number-thats-less-than-the-first-number-in-an-array-using But it seems like its a home-work problem and the "askers" are not giving enough time to it.

Comment: only put code where you face problem so that It's easy to read for others.

Comment: somebody asked the exact same question, today I think.

Comment: I tried thinking through it quite a bit before I decided to post. My bad. Did not know there was other people asking the same question.

Answer (score 1):

You’re running into an infinite recursion (this is usually the case when one gets `StackOverflowError` in a recursive program). You tried this code to stop the recursion:

```
    if (startIndex == endIndex) {
        if (numbers[endIndex] <= firstNumber)
            return numbers[startIndex];
    }
```

However, when `startIndex == endIndex` (your only chance), if `numbers[endIndex] > firstNumber`, this doesn’t stop the recursion, so it goes on — not infinitely, “only” until you hit a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. Now, however, on some test cases the method does not seem to work properly. With an input of: -31, -31,-31, -34, -34, -31, 0, -31, -34, -34, -31. It returns that the maximum value is 0. It seems to work properly when the first number is not negative.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity I tried input -1, -4, 0. Your program accepts no input after I have entered 0. It still examines all 100 numbers in your array, though. So your recursive method looks at ever shorter subarrays until startIndex and endIndex are both 1. At this point it return -4. Since -4 is not greater than the following element, 0, your method returns `numbers[endIndex]`, that is, 0, the rest of the way out.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to remove the nested `if` condition inside the first `if`. That is redundant as both `startIndex` and `endIndex` are same. Below should work:

```
private static int findMaxOfLessThanFirst(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex, int firstNumber) {
    if (startIndex == endIndex) {
        return numbers[startIndex];
    }
    int max = findMaxOfLessThanFirst(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1, firstNumber);
    if (max >= numbers[endIndex] && max <= firstNumber) {
        return max;
    }
    return numbers[endIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `else` branch. Where you have `if`, there must a `else`, I use this as a rule for programming. In some cases `else` maybe useless, in such cases I put some log info in `else`.

```
 private static int findMaxOfLessThanFirst(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex, int firstNumber) {
    if (startIndex == endIndex) {
        if (numbers[endIndex] <= firstNumber)
            return numbers[startIndex];          
        else return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    int max = findMaxOfLessThanFirst(numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1, firstNumber);
    if (max >= numbers[endIndex] && max<=firstNumber) {
        return max;
    }
    return numbers[endIndex];
}
```

Comment: I *think* you are on to something right. However, code only answers are not very useful. Perhaps you will want to explain what problem your code solves and how it solves it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just think lean things by thinking on the difference better than reading explanation ;)